# Publish C# project with database

Tags: c#

I'm currently learning C# with Visual Studio 2013 and planning to write an application with Database. There i have some questions:

1. What's the best database to publish with my application to
   friends/customers? The database won't be too big. And every user
   should use his own database.
2. How do i publish my application with the database and make an installer from it? I want to give customers a setup.exe that they can install. With everything they need, i.e. .net, database, etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to have a look at SqLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good [SQL Comparison Table](http://erikej.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html) that shows what you can and can't have with different options (SQL Server Express, Local DB, SQL Server Compact / CE).

You probably want SQL CE so you can bundle up an actual database file with your installer.

---

As for the installer, you'll need to create a Bootstrapper which will contain your installer + other installers you require + your database that you're releasing (assuming you mean a pre-populated database?).

Comment: so i can't use the rightclick on project-publish-method to publish the application with the database?

Comment: I think if you want to include other installers you need a bootstrapper. If you use SQL CE then you won't need another installer you can just bundle the DLLs in, I believe - that's a guess, though.

Comment: ok... i think i will use CE 4.0 and try installer on a fresh win8 VM.

Comment: is there a o/r designer for CE4.0?

Comment: Don't know, I'm afraid. MSDN says you can use [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546181.aspx). Could you use the designer with SQL Server Express and then, once you're done designing, change the connection to be SQL CE? - might be worth asking this as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

MS SQL Server Compact edition would be a good choice. It's free and redistributable with Your application. No extra installation needed. http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=17876

Comment: Sounds nice. Do i add the database to my project and when i publish the application, the sql compact will be installed with my application?

Comment: Yep, goes all with your installer.

Answer (score -1):

For really small databases, you could use [sqlite](https://system.data.sqlite.org).

Otherwise, I'd suggest using MS SQL Server, it has a free [Express edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx). I don't think attaching another install.exe would cause problems.

Comment: MS SQL Server is massive and requires very specific installation. Not good for "just packaging up with an application"